# Calling and executing javascript function from php echo call (print) internet explorer 7

Tags: php, javascript, printing, echo

I've got a problem with internet explorer not executing the javascript that I print out via php.  It works in all the other browsers; I've boiled it down to the essence of the issue.  This will not work in ie 7.

```
<?
echo '<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">alert("WTF");</script>';
<body></body></html>";
?>
```

Have also tried variations on type and language tags as well as doing stuff like this

```
echo "<html><head><script language='JavaScript'>alert('Captcha Failed');</script></head>
```

Anybody got any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: you can use the `{}` button to format code.

Comment: Your quotes are all messed up. Is that the way you have it in your code?

Comment: Pick one version of your code that works in other browsers but not IE, then use IE's View Source option and post a copy of the code as IE sees it. Posting several versions of the PHP all of which have mismatched quotes is not really helping us to help you...

Comment: sorry, that post got messed up... So how about this?  
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">alert('WTF');</script>  still doesn't work in ie 7. just straight up html with javascript

Comment: Sounds stupid but have you tried window.alert instead? Maybe IE7 won't pick up a straight up alert? Just a thought

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
  echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('WTF');</script>";
?>

<body></body></html>
```

Thats how I always do it.  I escape double quotes for HTML tag attributes and echo out with doubles too unless otherwise necessary.

Comment: Just tried that too... No dice, No alert or anything.  I'm running windows xp professional and ie 7, tried resetting all the security stuff (scripting permissions and whatnot) and still nothing.  Any other ideas?

Comment: So, I just tried to go to a javascript tutorial page and run their javascript on my ie7/xp combo and when I try to popup a new window through their javascript link it actually takes me to a new page instead of popping up a popup box, so the problem is not just my js .

Comment: I don't understand why that code wouldn't work.  I have the latest version of IE installed and I am not running any virtual machine software at present so I won't be able to test out things on IE7.  The new page you talk of, you mean a new tab? Or actually redirects the page your on to a new one? Because I have seen versions of IE confuse supposed new windows for new tabs.